# Why was Peeves in Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

Peeves was a poltergeist. It generally irritated people and rather then helping them as well as making fun of them.

- Why was Peeves in the school?
- What is/was the job or work assigned to Peeves?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Peeves was never a person, therefore it never had a job of work assigned to them.

JKR spoke to this issue directly on the FAQ on her [old website](http://web.archive.org/web/20070606212410/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=67)

> **Q : Peeves chews gum, how can he when he is a ghost? (Nearly Headless Nick can't eat).**
>
> *A : Peeves isn't a ghost; he was never a living person. He is an indestructible spirit of chaos, and solid enough to unscrew
>   chandeliers, throw walking sticks and, yes, chew gum.*

She's also provided some extra clarity in a [Leaky Cauldron](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-tlc_mugglenet-anelli-2.htm) interview in 2005

> **ES:** *Why does Dumbledore allow Peeves to stay in the castle?*
>
> **JKR:** *Can't get him out.*
>
> **ES:** *He's Dumbledore, he can do anything!*
>
> **JKR:** *No, no no no no. Peeves is like dry rot. You can try and eradicate it. It comes with the building. You’re stuck. If you've got
>   Peeves you're stuck.*
>
> **ES:** *But Peeves answers to Dumbledore -*
>
> **JKR:** *Allegedly.*
>
> **MA:** *Allegedly?*
>
> **JKR:** *Yeah. I see Peeves as like a severe plumbing problem in a very old building, and Dumbledore is slightly better with the spanner
>   than most people, so he can maybe make it function better for a few
>   weeks. Then it’s going to start leaking again. Would you want Peeves
>   gone, honestly?*
>
> **MA:** *If I was Harry I might, but as a reader I enjoy him. I enjoyed him most when he started obeying Fred and George at the end of
>   book five.*
>
> **JKR:** *Yeah, that was fun. I enjoyed that. That was satisfying.* [Laughter.]

Comment: Dobby wasn't a human, yet he procured employment at Hogwarts through Dumbledore. Firenze was a teacher and he was a centaur. Professor Binns was a ghost and a teacher. Hagrid was half giant, Lupin a werewolf. The latter two being half-human and human respectively. Just thought I'd point that out. Oh, in case we ever have need of it, remember that Professor Lupin taught us the spell *Waddiwasi* will shoot a wad of chewing gum from the Dark Arts classroom door's lock directly up Peeves' nose! :P Nice answer +1

Comment: @Slytherincess - Are you saying that Dobby isn't a person?

Comment: @Richard she said human

Answer (score 7):

### Peeves was *generated* inside Hogwarts.

> The poltergeist is an invisible entity that moves objects, slams doors and creates other audible, kinetic disturbances. It has been reported in many cultures and there is a strong association with the places where young people, especially adolescents, are living. Explanations for the phenomenon vary all the way from supernatural to scientific.
>
> **It was inevitable that, in a building bursting with teenage witches and wizards, a poltergeist would be generated;** it was likewise to be expected that such a poltergeist would be noisier, more destructive and harder to expel than those that occasionally frequent Muggle houses.
>  *Source : [Pottermore - Peeves](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/peeves)*